# Testing 'An existing connection can be disconnected from Apps.com' C2QB WF5.0

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am going over the checklist of QB requirements and currently looking at C2QB WF5.0. The steps are:

```
Go here: https://appcenter.intuit.com
/Home/ManageSubscriptions/.
On the Manage My Apps tab, locate the app and click the Disconnect link.
On the Confirm Disconnect dialog, click the Yes, Disconnect App button.
On the Confirm Disconnect dialog, click the Next button.
Sign in to the app.
```

As I using a staging (not authorized) version of the app it does not seem to show up in Apps.com for my QB user. Is there a way to either make the app show in https://appcenter.intuit.com/Home/ManageSubscriptions/ or to test this requirement in some other way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simulate the proper flow you can simply paste the Disconnect URL into the browser after the App Center completes the disconnect process. Intuit uses this method to complete the testing during the technical review .

Thanks